# Cannot get filter option working in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a simple piece of code. I'm trying to filter on a property in a geoJson using the polyline class to draw only that feature. Console is logging no errors and no line features draw. Any obvious errors to folks?

```
var featuredTrails = {"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}},
"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":0,"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.61021404499996,37.912006417000043],[-122.61030149899995,37.911962580000079],[-122.61032215499995,37.91195437500005],[-122.61034267899998,37.911948396000071],[-122.61037064499999,37.911944185000038],[-122.61044270799999,37.911944840000046],[-122.61048737499999,37.911941983000077],[-122.61051446199997,37.911935416000063],[-122.61056354999999,37.911913854000034],[-122.61058265499997,37.911907477000057],[-122.61060151699996,37.911905097000044],[-122.61065930899997,37.911903652000035],[-122.61068899199995,37.911899589000029],[-122.61071666799995,37.911890815000049],[-122.61076069999996,37.911863463000032],[-122.61100599899999,37.911912114000074],[-122.61115807299996,37.912020056000074]]},"properties":{"FID":0,"OBJECTID":1,"trailName":"West Peak Loop","SHAPE_Leng":0.0010123783761800001,"Length_mi":0}}

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="data/OneTamFeaturedTrailheads.js"></script>
  <script src="data/OneTamFeaturedTrails.js"></script>

    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [37.887914, -122.578138],
      zoom: 12,
    });

      var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-background/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
        attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 18,
        ext: 'png'
      });
      tiles.addTo(map);


  var westPeak = L.geoJson(featuredTrailHeads, {
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latLng);
    },
    // set marker style
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
      color: '#000000',
      fillColor: '#f6c65b',
      weight: 1,
      stroke: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      radius: 5
      }
    }
   }).addTo(map); 

 var trailsLayer =  L.geoJson(featuredTrails, {
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latLngs){
     return L.polyline (feature, latLngs);
   },
  filter: function(feature, latLngs) {
    if (feature.properties.trailName["West Peak Loop"])

          return feature
   },
 }).addTo(map); 

    </script>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the relevant GeoJSON data. Although, the `if` statement inside your `filter` method seems off. What value is `feature.properties.trailName`?

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier - I updated the code sample to include a piece of the Json

Comment: I'm beginning to think this has to do with how the geoJson is formatted. Might try and use another tool to convert from shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your geoJson is wrong. You have to add `]}` at the end.

Also the if in your code is wrong. `feature.properties.trailName["West Peak Loop"]` with that you are getting the child "West Peak Loop" from the object "trailName", but there is no object with the name "West Peak Loop".

And in the filter function you have to return `true` or `false`.

Update your filter to:

```
  filter: function(feature, latLngs) {
    if (feature.properties.trailName == "West Peak Loop"){
          return true;
    }
   },
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/cLtvgphr/

Comment: Thanks! I see that "West Peak Loop" is the value of the key trailName., that is clear. I didn't include the ]) as a result of copy and paste. That was not the whole geoJson file.

Comment: It also seems return feature or true works. is one better than the other? I've used feature more often than the boolean option.

Comment: yes you can use the feature in the return, because it tests if the feature is a object with data what is always true. You can do it like you want, but for the readable code it is better to use true, also maybe you can think that it returns the full feature and that is not so, it only returns true or false